# Reshape numpy nested array into array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array with shape likes

```
a1.shape
# 1000
a1[0].shape
# (100, 100, 3)
```

I want to change the shape in the way that

```
a1.shape
# (1000, 100, 100, 3)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are all elements of `a1` the same shape?

Comment: yes, all elements have the same shape

Comment: try `np.stack(a1)`

Comment: I tried but a1.shape is still (1000, )

Comment: yes, I created the array in this way <br/>
    fl1 = glob.glob(‘img/*.jpg')
    x1 = np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname)) for fname in fl1])
    for i in range(0, len(x1)):
      x1[i] = imresize(x1[i], [100,100], interp='bilinear')

Comment: Skip the `np.array` when first making `x1`.  Collect the arrays in a list, and do the resize on the elements of that list.  Then verify the `shape`.  If all elements in the list have the same shape, then `np.array(x1)` will produce the desired multidimensional array.  Unless you are doing something clever, an object array of arrays is always the result of variable shapes.

Comment: oh, it works. thanks @hpaulj

Comment: @hpaulj could you please explain how this works? Because I think two initial np.array do the same as create a list then convert to multidimensional array. Also is there any way if we already have an array (1000,) and reshape it into (1000, 100, 100, 3). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make a list of arrays with differing shapes (but same  number of elements):

```
In [72]: alist = [np.ones((2,3),int),np.zeros(6,int),np.arange(6)]
In [73]: alist
Out[73]: 
[array([[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]]), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])]
In [74]: np.array(alist)
Out[74]: 
array([array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]]), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
       array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])], dtype=object)
```

The result is an object dtype array.

But if we reshape all elements of the list to the same shape, we get a 3d array:

```
In [75]: np.array([x.reshape(2,3) for x in alist])
Out[75]: 
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]]])
```

Now lets try reshaping elements after making the array:

```
In [76]: arr = np.array(alist)
In [77]: arr.shape
Out[77]: (3,)
In [78]: for i in range(3):
    ...:     arr[i] = arr[i].reshape(2,3)
    ...:     
In [79]: arr
Out[79]: 
array([array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]]),
       array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]]),
       array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])], dtype=object)
In [80]: np.array(arr)
Out[80]: 
array([array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]]),
       array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]]),
       array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])], dtype=object)
```

Calling `array` on that array doesn't change anything.

But `stack` does work (`stack` is just a convenient version of `concatenate`):

```
In [82]: np.stack(arr)
Out[82]: 
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]]])
```

`stack` takes a list of arrays, or it is an array, iterates on the 1st dimension:

```
In [83]: np.stack([x for x in arr])
Out[83]: 
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]]])
```

Answer (score -1):

Just post a solution in case anyone needs

```
x = []
for fname in fl1:
    x.append( np.array(Image.open(fname)))

for i in range(0, len(x)):
  x[i] = imresize(x[i], [100,100], interp='bilinear')   

y = np.array(x)
y.shape
```